# Android fmod not working properly on android 2.1

Tags: android, fmod

My game engine is using fmod library for sound functions. After testing the project on different android phone, i found that fmod is working correctly for android 2.2 and above but not on android 2.1. I observed that example project's manifest file mention minimum sdk version 8 (android 2.2). My client want game to able to play from android 2.1 and above. And one more strange observations, when i install and run game on android 2.1 phone, my app terminate automatically but when i run my game on android 2.1 emulator, my game work correctly, except that sound is muted, i.e. , inaudible. 
This is error message i got when run on android 2.1 hardware :

> FMOD error! (48) Tried to use a feature that requires hardware support. (ie trying to play a GCADPCM compressed sound in software on Wii).

Please help me by answering these questions :

1> Is it true fmod can't work on android 2.1? if not, can you suggest how to run it.

2> Any alternate solution for sound to work on android 2.1 and above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems fmod support all android versions. The message :

> FMOD error! (48) Tried to use a feature that requires hardware support. (ie trying to play a GCADPCM compressed sound in software on Wii).

is caused due to hardware not supported for floating point calculations.
[Here](http://www.fmod.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=15057&p=51258#p51258) is the details.